# File Upload Access with Django

Tags: django, subprocess

I'm trying to take a user uploaded file and run it through another process and get the output.

This is what I currently have:

```
from subprocess import check_output

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            output = check_output(['/home/username/app', request.FILES['file']])
            return HttpResponse(output)
        except:
            return HttpResponse('<a href="/">Home</a>')
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

So if I wanted to pass the file as a command line argument into /home/username/app, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to save it to disk first.

[`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) might be useful.